# Problems setting the correct file name to ImageViewer

Tags: iphone, image-viewer

I am trying to pass the value of a string from an array to an instance of `ImageViewer` when building a table view cell, but I am getting nil values. Here is the code:

```
NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] init ];
file = [photoFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

ImageViewer *imageView  = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewer" bundle:nil];
imageView.fileName = file;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:imageView animated:YES];
[imageView release];
```

Can you help me please to fix this problem?

Comment: Where do you find this `nil` value? It is unclear from your question.

Comment: here is nil ..imageView.fileName = file; I checked with brekpoint

Comment: What is nil here? `file`? If so you should check the contents of the `photoFiles` array

Comment: Please, check my answer below, I added some interesting info you should look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `imageView.fileName = file` is setting a `nil` value, you probably should consider analyzing the contents of the `photoFiles` array.

It could be possible that this array has no values at the `indexPath.row` index. You should check this through the debugger, or with a log print:

```
NSLog(@"Array contents: %@", [photoFiles description]);
```

#### Edit

You could write this code in a more concise way. I.e.:

```
ImageViewer *imageView  = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewer" bundle:nil];
imageView.fileName = [photoFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:imageView animated:YES];
[imageView release];
```

Also, you should avoid pointing to a `nil` `NSBundle`. I.e. Change the first row to:

```
ImageViewer *imageView  = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewer" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

But it should work also this way, since the class name and the Nib name are the same:

```
ImageViewer *imageView  = [[ImageViewer alloc] init];
```

Try it and let me know if something changed.

Comment: Ok I am using sections ..if(indexPath.section == 1) { file = [photofiles objectAtIndex:indexPAth.row]}

Answer (score 1):

check the line

```
file = [photoFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and

Check the properties  for **filename**  in **imageviewer**

Comment: I set property for it and And Put NSLOG(@"%@",filename) It is giving Null

Comment: check NSLOG(@"%@%@", imageView.filename,file)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't have to allocate memory to **NSString**. Secondly, have you set properties for **fileName** in **ImageViewer**?

Comment: I set property in imageviewer..I am trying to get image name in string.And this same is working fine for textfile name

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's not enough information here to give an answer (you'll need to step through it with a debugger and figure out why you're getting a nil value back), and you have at least one memory leak. Here's how I'd rewrite the code you present:

```
ImageViewer *imageView  = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewer" bundle:nil];
imageView.fileName = [photoFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:imageView animated:YES];
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my way to do That ... may be this will help you ...

I am having NSarray in my table view ... and the next view I have NsDictionary

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int actualRowIndex = [[filteredIndexs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];

    [_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    selectedMeal *selctedMealView = [[selectedMeal alloc]   initWithNibName:@"selectedMeal" bundle:nil];
    selctedMealView.offerDetails = [offers objectAtIndex:actualRowIndex];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:selctedMealView animated:YES];
    //[selctedMealView changeText:[arryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [selctedMealView release];
}
```

in here selectedmeal is my next View and offers is my NSArray in table View also the offerDetails is my NSDictionary in selected meal view

also in table View I created NSdictionary and settheobject like this

```
NSString *o_resturant_name = [offer objectForKey:@"restaurant_name"];
[[Globals sharedGlobals].resturantList addObject:o_resturant_name];
```

and the selectedmeal view in viewdidload I read that value ...

```
NSString *resturantNameText = [offerDetails objectForKey:@"restaurant_name"];
```

This is working perfectly for me ...

may be this will help you